# What can I do to not repeat code in xaml?

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I've been working with delphi for a year already and now I'll develop some C# UWP.
 I already have done some work, and I can see that in my XAML there are like 1000 lines..BECAUSE I have to do 10 'Panels' exactly identic, only changing their names, example:

```
<StackPanel Name="Stack1">
    <TextBlock Name="Text1"/>
    <TextBox Name="Box1" 
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Name="Stack2">
    <TextBlock Name="Text2"/>
    <TextBox Name="Box2" 
</StackPanel>
```

this is just a example, actually my code have 100 lines each 'StackPanel'.
so.. theres a way to do only 1 'StackPanel' and use it as a class or something on XAML code 10 times using few lines
 or I'll have to write it 10 times and use 1000 lines

Comment: SO doesn't want n-in-1 questions, where n > 1. And your first question is really of very limited usefulness. You don't pick controls based on how commonly they are used. You have requirements and pick the best match. The second question is unanswerable given the information provided.

Comment: @IInspectable Hello, since the first one is a "true/false" question, I thought it was pointless to create another question, sorry

Comment: The first question is pointless to ask, regardless of whether it's part of another question, or a stand-alone question. It doesn't make sense to ask, how popular any particular control is. Pick the one that matches your requirements. If you don't know your requirements, you should go back to the drawing board.

Comment: @IInspectable ok I removed that one, even though Im curious about which one is most used or which one they've used in MoneyApp or any other Win10 App. if they mix panels or keep using one.

Comment: *"which one they've used in [...] any other Win10 App"* - Every control has been used in one or more apps. There, now that's out of the way, and you can concentrate on real issues.

Comment: Where do you want to use it? Inside a grid, as datatemplate or somewhere else?

Comment: @HasanHasanov Sorry I'm new at UWP so I only know grid at the moment, but if theres other possibilities to show to user, I'll certainly study about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use good old user control. Here I provided you with an example:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App1.ReusableCode"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="SomeText" />
            <TextBlock Text="Some Text 2" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Name="stackPanel2" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="SomeText 3" />
            <TextBlock Text="Some Text 4" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Name="stackPanel3" Grid.Row="2">
            <TextBlock Text="SomeText 5" />
            <TextBlock Text="Some Text 6" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Name="stackPanel4" Grid.Row="3">
            <TextBlock Text="SomeText 7" />
            <TextBlock Text="Some Text 8" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

You can use it in your views like this:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <local:ReusableCode x:Name="ucReusableCode" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

If your usercontrol is located inside a folder you have to export it like this.

```
xmlns:usercontrol="using:App1.UserControlsFolder"
```

Which is inside your Page xaml and can call it like this:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:usercontrol="using:App1.UserControlsFolder"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <usercontrol:ReusableCode x:Name="ucReusableCode" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for later answer, but this will work too, now im using C# everyday in work ( I was using delphi ) and home, im kinda knowing a lot things now, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is a [ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.aspx), or the controls derived from `ItemsControl` like [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx). For example here:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind itemscontrolCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}" />
                <TextBox />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Code behind:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<ItemsControlList> itemscontrolCollection;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    itemscontrolCollection = new ObservableCollection<ItemsControlList>();
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    itemscontrolCollection.Clear();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        itemscontrolCollection.Add(new ItemsControlList { MyText = "Text" + i });
    }
}
```

My `ItemsControlList` class:

```cs
public class ItemsControlList
{
    public string MyText { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know why you set names to each `StackPanel`, `TextBlock` and `TextBox` here, you can use [data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/data-binding/index) to set value to the dependency properties of each control.

You can check the official [ListView and GridView sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlListView) to check how to use `ListView` in UWP app. And you can also refer to [UI basics (XAML) sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlUIBasics) to find which control is more suitable for your scenario.